# Is it safe to store bird seed in plastic trash bags? (Inside those big yellow cat litter bins)

Tags: birds

My wife loves her bird feeders. The problem with this is that we either store bird seed outside and the birds get to it, making a big paper mess, or we store it inside. Storing it inside, we have to worry about kicking around a big bag of bird seed (Storage space is at a premium at our house, so it has to sit by the back door). I'm thinking it wouldn't be a bad idea to store the seed in trash bags inside one of those big yellow plastic cat litter tubs.

The question here is it safe for the birds? I'm vaguely aware that some plastics are not food safe and will seep toxins, and neither trash bags nor kitty litter boxes seem like good candidates for manufacturers to test against for food safety. If regular trash bags are an issue, is there any sort of material that is safe for this type of storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://birding.about.com/od/birdfeeders/a/birdseedstorage.htm) guide recommends storing it inside plastic zip bags, and also suggests galvanised metal cans for storing the seed outside. We actually keep ours in plastic tubs, the kind you get ice cream in, though for something bigger you could use cereal tubs, or anything else that has been deemed safe for storage of human foods.